# Generate @Component definitions runtime for Angular Component Tests

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this Angular 11 component I want to test:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo-page',
  template: `
    <app-header mode='operational' cool='true'></app-header>
    Some content
  `
})
export class FooPageComponent { }
```

I could put `HeaderComponent` in the `declarations` like so:

```
 setUpTestBed({
   declarations: [
     FooPageComponent,
     HeaderComponent,
   ],
```

But I often prefer this

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-header', template: 'dummy' })
class DummyHeaderComponent {
  @Input() mode = 'operational';
  @Input() cool = true;
}

// ...

  setUpTestBed({
    declarations: [
      FooPageComponent,
      DummyHeaderComponent,
    ],
```

Here comes the question: **can I somehow create a *function* to return such 'dummy' components?** I would like to shorten things into a helper method I can use to build the `declarations` when testing my pages, without having to create an explicit dummy component each time.

Put differently, I wish I could write:

```
function generateDummyComponentDefinition(selector, inputs) {
  // Return a class or constructor function
  // ...that is @Component(...) decorated properly
  // ...that has @Input() properties as specified
}

// ...

  setUpTestBed({
    declarations: [
      FooPageComponent,
      generateDummyComponentDefinition('app-header', ['mode', 'cool']),
    ],
```

I read through [TypeScript's Decorators documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) but the gap to my practical scenario is a bit big.

Is what I want even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible with the following dynamic code:

```
function generateDummyComponentDefinition(selector: string, inputs: string[]) {
  @Component({
    selector,
    template: 'dummy'
  })
  class DummyComponent {
    static propDecorators = inputs.reduce((acc, input) => {
      acc[input] = [{type: Input}];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

  return DummyComponent;
}
```

Angular compiler can recognize `propDecorators` which should be an object of all property's decorators.

Comment: Side note: does `propDecorators` rely on internals of Angular, or is it part of the public API? (Put differently: will this likely break in future major Angular updates?)

Comment: It was with Angular long time ago and still here. It's partly private but on the other side it's public because libraries use that